# How to install and start phpPGAdmin

Tags: database, postgresql, phppgadmin

This may be a very silly question, but I can't figure out how to use the phpPGAdmin. I've downloaded and unzipped the .zip file from the website, but how do I install it? I'm using a Mac.

I'm starting a lift project on a remote server and would like to have phpPgadmin installed on my Mac so that i can connect to the postgresql db on the remote host through phpPgAdmin's GUI.

I'm very new to databases and this is all very confusing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using XAMPP:

http://practicalfoss.blogspot.com/2008/09/how-to-install-postgresql-and.html

If you are not:

http://www.farces.com/wikis/naked-server/phppgadmin/

Answer (score 1):

if you will use XAMPP and follow the above link provided by user2615534 there is a chance that you get access forbidden. So, how to fix that:

In the step where you open c:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp.conf

**REMEMBER** to add "Require local" in  tag ;)
Worked for me!

It will be like that:

```
<IfModule mime_module>
    Alias /phppgadmin "C:/xampp/phpPgAdmin/"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/phpPgAdmin">
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
        Require local
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
```